# Ubuntu 20.04 Error: Opening the Cache

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dependencies, cache

I have been getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T25sR.png) for months:

```
Error: Opening the cache(E: can not open /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened
This usually means your installed package have unmet dependencies
```

Then I try to fix it with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

I tried these to no effect. Sometimes the error goes away for a while but then it comes back in a few minutes.

I also tried this

[image: contents of /var/crash]

Are the crash/whoopsie files related to the error?

Comment: No pictures of text please include the test in the body of the message,

Comment: sorry I'm a new user. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Does the directory /var/lib/apt/lists/ exist and have correct rights ? What is the output of `ls -ld /var?/lib/apt/lists/` ?

Comment: ls: cannot access 'var?/lib/apt/lists/'  No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

This will occasionally happen when your `apt` lists are incomplete or broken. You can rebuild them like this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Remove the contents of the `lists` directory:

   ```
   sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
   ```
2. Rebuild the lists:

   ```
   sudo apt clean
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Update your system:

   ```
   sudo apt dist-upgrade
   ```

Hope this allows you to have an up-to-date system again

Comment: The same error is displayed again. It only disaapeared for a while.

Comment: If the files in this directory are regularly being corrupted, then `apt` is being cancelled mid-process or your storage device is failing.

Comment: How can I check the problem can you please tell me